# overrides ToString() of a POCO used by NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, poco

how can I override ToStringmethod in a POCO object used as NHibernate model entity?
To override object.ToString() you should declare something like

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return "my string here";
    }
```

But NHibernate wants everything inside the POCO mapped objects to be virtual... and you can't declare a method both virtual ad override.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you are overriding the method means that it's virtual, there should be no problem.

Comment: true. I don't know what was going, but I had an NHibernate error message saying that the method must be declared virtual... now I tried again and the message disappered... probably there was something else wrong in my code

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason to override ToString? Is it for debugging purposes? If so, while this doesn't actually answer your question, you could look at [Debugger Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

My C# and NHibernate are both a bit rusty but I believe

```
public virtual string ToString()
{
    return "my string here";
}
```

is perfectly valid code.

The generated proxy should then use the provided implementation of ToString

Comment: this way you are shadowing Object.ToString(), not overriding it